# Read JSON file, parse and import to Parse

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I have defined a Parse Cloud function that fetches a JSON file. I now need to read the JSON data and parse it so I can populate one of my classes with the results. The trouble is, I am struggling knowing how to parse the data before calling an import. Can anyone point me in the right direction please on parsing the data.

My Cloud function is as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello1", function(request, response) {
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: '{feed_url_here}',
    params: {
        'LastRequest':'0',
        'SubscriberKey':'{access_key_here}',
    }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(httpResponse.text)
},
function (error) {
    response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
}); });
```

A sample of my JSON is:

```
{"sports-content":{"sport-event":[{"event-metadata":{"league":"NHL Hockey","event-type":"0","league-details":"NHL","event-date-time":"12/03/2015 07:00 PM","eventNum":"2991830","status":"FINAL","off-the-board":"False"},"team":[{"team-metadata":{"alignment":"Home","nss":"2","openNum":"1","name":{"full":"New York Rangers"}},"wagering-stats":{"wagering-straight-spread":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"-1.5","money":"210","context":"current"},"wagering-moneyline":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"-135","context":"current"},"wagering-total":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"5.5","money":"-130","context":"current"}},"team-stats":{"score":"1"}},{"team-metadata":{"alignment":"Away","openNum":"0","nss":"1","name":{"full":"Colorado Avalanche"}},"wagering-stats":{"wagering-straight-spread":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"1.5","money":"-260","context":"current"},"wagering-moneyline":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"115","context":"current"},"wagering-total":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"5.5","money":"110","context":"current"}},"team-stats":{"score":"2"}}]},{"event-metadata":{"league":"NHL Hockey","event-type":"0","league-details":"NHL","event-date-time":"12/03/2015 07:00 PM","eventNum":"2991840","status":"FINAL","off-the-board":"False"},"team":[{"team-metadata":{"alignment":"Home","nss":"4","openNum":"1","name":{"full":"Carolina Hurricanes"}},"wagering-stats":{"wagering-straight-spread":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"-1.5","money":"200","context":"current"},"wagering-moneyline":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"-145","context":"current"},"wagering-total":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"5.0","money":"-140","context":"current"}},"team-stats":{"score":"1"}},{"team-metadata":{"alignment":"Away","openNum":"0","nss":"3","name":{"full":"New Jersey Devils"}},"wagering-stats":{"wagering-straight-spread":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"1.5","money":"-240","context":"current"},"wagering-moneyline":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"125","context":"current"},"wagering-total":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"5.0","money":"120","context":"current"}},"team-stats":{"score":"5"}}]},{"event-metadata":{"league":"NHL Hockey","event-type":"0","league-details":"NHL","event-date-time":"12/03/2015 07:30 PM","eventNum":"2991860","status":"FINAL","off-the-board":"False"},"team":[{"team-metadata":{"alignment":"Home","nss":"6","openNum":"1","name":{"full":"Ottawa Senators"}},"wagering-stats":{"wagering-straight-spread":{"bookmaker-name":"CRIS","active":"true","line":"1.5","money":"-260","context":"current"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like a call to good ol' `JSON.parse()`

`response.success(JSON.parse(httpResponse.text));`

Although you'll probably want to wrap it in a `try/catch` as JSON parsing can get hairy sometimes.

```
try {
    response.success(JSON.parse(httpResponse.text));
} catch(e) {
    throw new Error("I don't know what that is");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the output is a lot more readable now (\'s removed etc).. Is there a xmlreader.js type equivalent for json data that I can utilise to format / read the data to select which parts to insert into my parse classes? Thanks.

Comment: @RJH, unless I'm misunderstanding you, you just want to access parts of the data that's returned? What's returned is the json object, so you have access to its parts like any other object `varname["sports-content"]` is a valid operation. You could also pass the return data (json) over to another function to sort what you want/don't want

Comment: Thanks. A strange thing that happens when using JSON.parse is that if I do: response.success(JSON.parse(httpResponse.text)); it outputs the full feed content. If I use console.log(JSON.parse(httpResponse.text)); it outputs the first field but then the remaining are blank.. for example: {"sports-content":{"sport-event":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}   Any thoughts?

Comment: @RJH, well based on your JSON sample, you aren't producing valid markup

Comment: hmm. When I paste the output into JSON to CSV convertor it is reading correctly. The output to my shell reads like a JSON format, so the JSON.parse isn't losing any of the data, its just when I console.log the data it blanks all but the first two fields.. weird? Could this be because parse.com log lines are limited to 1KB after which they are truncated?

Comment: @RJH could you provide your json?

Comment: Fixed it... I was using: var temp = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text); but it works if I do it with: var temp = httpResponse.text; JSON.parse(temp); Thanks for your continued efforts :)